# Modification of non-creatable array value attempted

Tags: perl

I'm not experienced in perl and I'm having difficulty troubleshooting this error. Any help is appreciated. Script as follows (reported problem on line 40, in bold):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

print "Please enter filename (without extension): ";
$input = <>;
chomp ($input);

print "Please enter total no. of sequence in fasta file: ";
$orig_size= <>*2-1;
chomp ($orig_size);

open (INFILE, "$input.fasta") or die "Error opening input file for shuffling!";
open (SHUFFLED, ">"."$input"."_shuffled.fasta") or die "Error creating shuffled output file!";

@array = (0); # Need to initialise 1st element in array1&2 for the shift function
@array2 = (0);
$i = 1;
$index = 0;
$index2 = 0;

while (my @line=<INFILE>){
    while ($i<=$orig_size) { 

    $array[$i] = $line[$index];
    $array[$i]=~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg;

    $index++;
    $array2[$i] = $line[$index];
    $array2[$i]=~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg;

    $i++;
    $index++;
    }
}

my $array = shift (@array); 
**my $array2 = shift (@array2);**
for ($i = $header_size; --$i; ) { 
    my $j = int rand ($i+1);
    next if $i == $j;
    @array[$i,$j] = @array[$j,$i];
    @array2[$i,$j] = @array2[$j,$i];
}

while ($index2<=$header_size) { 
    print SHUFFLED "$array[$index2]\n";
    print SHUFFLED "$array2[$index2]\n";
    $index2++;
}
close(INFILE);
close(SHUFFLED);
```

Comment: You would be well served to **always** use the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas.  You will be amply rewarded.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
Modification of non-creatable array value attempted
```

As explained [here](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/perl/perldoc/manual/perldiag.html):

> You tried to make an array value spring into existence, and the
>   subscript was probably negative, even counting from end of the array
>   backwards.

Leads me to believe that you have counted your lines wrong, and it is referring to this block:

```
for ($i = $header_size; --$i; ) {
```

Meaning that you have taken the loop too far, and `$i` has become negative, and gone beyond the size of the array. The reason it has is that `$header_size` is not defined (which translates to zero). As a side note, this problem would not have existed if you had used a proper for loop:

```
for ($i = $header_size; $i >= 0; $i--)
```

Or better yet, a perl-style loop:

```
for my $i (0 .. $header_size)
```

Even though this would iterate in the reverse order, it would not matter in this case.

Your code is somewhat illegible to me, but I assume this block is meant to shuffle your array. For this purpose, it is better to use the `shuffle` function from the [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil) module. It is a core module since perl v5.7.3. E.g.

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);
...
my @shuffled_indexs = shuffle 0..$#array;
@array  = @array [@shuffled_indexes];
@array2 = @array2[@shuffled_indexes];
```

It is worth repeating that writing code without using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Is a very bad idea indeed. It will allow silent errors and typos and it will make your debugging a great deal more difficult.

Comment: His shuffling algorithm is the same as List::Util's, but it works in-place.

Comment: Your loop is probably off by one. (Hard to tell since $header_size doesn't exist) If so, one could use `for (my $i = $header_size-1 ; $i >= 0; $i--)` or `for (my $i = $header_size ; $i--; )`

Comment: Thanks for the input, folks. I changed my for loop to: for ($i = $header_size; $i >= 0; $i--) but now I get a different error. Namely, Error opening input file for shuffling! at fasta_corrector3.pl line 11, <> line 2. Is my input of "<>" incorrect?

Comment: Ok, I have it working now, sort of. Using any of the suggested loops seems to work, but the output file only has a single sequence in it. Suggestions?

Comment: No, it is meaningless to guess. Ask a new question and show your code.