# perl: Use of uninitialized value and output is truncated

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the following script to shuffle the order of sequences (lines) within a file. I'm not sure how to "initialize" values -- please help!

```
print "Please enter filename (without extension): ";
my $input = <>;
chomp $input;

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Please enter total no. of sequence in fasta file: ";
my $orig_size = <>*2-1;
chomp $orig_size;

open INFILE, "$input.fasta"
   or die "Error opening input file for shuffling!";
open SHUFFLED, ">"."$input"."_shuffled.fasta"
   or die "Error creating shuffled output file!";

my @array  = (0); # Need to initialise 1st element in array1&2 for the shift function
my @array2 = (0);
my $i      = 1;
my $index  = 0;
my $index2 = 0;

while (my @line = <INFILE>){

    while ($i <= $orig_size) { 

        $array[$i] = $line[$index];
        $array[$i] =~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg;

        $index++;
        $array2[$i] = $line[$index];
        $array2[$i] =~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg;

        $i++;
        $index++;
    }
}

my $array  = shift (@array); 
my $array2 = shift (@array2);

for ($i = my $header_size; $i >= 0; $i--) { 

    my $j = int rand ($i+1);
    next if $i == $j;
    @array[$i,$j]  = @array[$j,$i];
    @array2[$i,$j] = @array2[$j,$i];
}

while ($index2 <= my $header_size) { 

    print SHUFFLED "$array[$index2]\n";
    print SHUFFLED "$array2[$index2]\n";
    $index2++;
}
close INFILE;
close SHUFFLED;
```

I'm getting these warnings:

`Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at fasta_corrector6.pl line 27, <INFILE> line 578914.

Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at fasta_corrector6.pl line 31, <INFILE> line 578914.

Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at fasta_corrector6.pl line 40, <INFILE> line 578914.

Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at fasta_corrector6.pl line 41, <INFILE> line 578914.

Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at fasta_corrector6.pl line 42, <INFILE> line 578914.

Use of uninitialized value in numeric le (<=) at fasta_corrector6.pl line 47, <INFILE> line 578914.

Use of uninitialized value in numeric le (<=) at fasta_corrector6.pl line 50, <INFILE> line 578914.`

Comment: Do the line numbers in your warnings correspond to the line numbers in the code sample? If not, please indicate where the warnings occur.

Comment: Sorry, the line numbers actually correspond to +2 in the code sample (as in, line 27 is line 25 in the code sample)

Comment: Do you have 578914 lines in your input file? That will consume a ton of memory if you intend to load entire files into arrays.

Comment: The 25th line of your code sample is: `while($i <= $orig_size)`, and there is no regex substitution in that line. However, it might not hurt to make sure that `$orig_size` is defined.

Comment: `while (my @line = <INFILE>){` will read all the lines of `INFILE` at once (slurp the file). It will run the loop once, then move on.

Answer (score 3):

First, you read the whole input file in:

```
  use IO::File;
  my @lines = IO::File->new($file_name)->getlines;
```

then you shuffle it:

```
  use List::Util 'shuffle';
  my @shuffled_lines = shuffle(@lines);
```

then you write them out:

```
  IO::File->new($new_file_name, "w")->print(@shuffled_lines);
```

There's an entry in the Perl FAQ about [how to shuffle an array](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-shuffle-an-array-randomly%3f). Another entry [tells of the many ways to read a file in one go](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-an-entire-file-all-at-once%3f). Perl FAQs contain a lot of samples and trivia on how to do many common things -- it's a good place to continue learning more about Perl.

Comment: This look very useful and much less complicated than my current script. However, it still only returns a single line from the original file. Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux? If you have a file with multiple lines, but you are only getting one line then it is possible there is a line ending mismatch (e.g. CR vs. CRLF vs. LF). `IO::File` is used in the example above **without** binary flag ("b"), so it should work.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. I'm not sure what the line ending mismatch means - can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot pinpoint what exactly went wrong, but there are a few oddities with your code:

#### The Diamond Operator

Perl's Diamond operator `<FILEHANDLE>` reads a line from the filehandle. If no filehandle is provided, each command line Argument (`@ARGV`) is treated as a file and read. If there are no arguments, `STDIN` is used. better specify this yourself. You also should `chomp` *before* you do arithemtics with the line, not afterwards. Note that strings that do not start with a number are treated as numeric `0`. You should check for numericness (with a regex?) and include error handling.

The Diamond/Readline operator is context sensitive. If given in scalar context (e.g, a conditional, a scalar assignment) it returns one line. If given in list context, e.g. as a function parameter or *an array assignment*, it returns *all lines* as an array. So

```
while (my @line = <INFILE>) { ...
```

will not give you one line but all lines and is thus equivalent to

```
my @line;
if (@line = <INFILE>) { ...
```

#### Array gymnastics

After you read in the lines, you try to do some manual chomping. Here I remove all trailing whitspaces in `@line`, in a single line:

```
s/\s+$// foreach @line;
```

And here, I remove all non-leading whitespaces (what your regex is doing in fact):

```
s/(?<!^)\s//g foreach @line;
```

To stuff an element alternatingly into two arrays, this might work as well:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#@line) {
   if ($i % 2) {
     push @array1, shift @line;
   } else {
     push @array2, shift @line;
   }
}
```

or

```
my $i = 0;
while (@line) {
   push ($i++ % 2 ? @array1 : @array2), shift @line
}
```

Manual bookkeeping of array indices is messy and error-prone.

Your for-loop could be written mor idiomatic as

```
for my $i (reverse 0 .. $header_size)
```

Do note that declaring `$header_size` inside the loop initialisation is possible if it was not declared before, but it will yield the `undef` value, therefore you assigned `undef` to `$i` which leads to some of the error messages, as `undef` should not be used in arithemtic operations. Assignments always assigns the right side to the left side.

Comment: `@line = map { s/\s+$// } @line` -- will not work. Add the `/r` modifier, or `; $_` to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

On your previous question I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12357923/725418), and noted that your code failed because you had not initialized a variable named `$header_size` used in a loop condition. Not only have you repeated that mistake, you have elaborated on it by starting to declare the variable with `my` each time you try to access it.

```
for ($i = my $header_size; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
#         ^^--- wrong!

while ($index2 <= my $header_size) { 
#                 ^^--- wrong!
```

A variable that is declared with `my` is empty (`undef`) by default. `$index2` can never contain anything but `undef` here, and your loop will run only once, because `0 <= undef` will evaluate true (albeit with an uninitialized warning).

Please take my advice and set a value for `$header_size`. And only use `my` when declaring a variable, not every time you use it.

**A better solution**

Seeing your errors above, it seems that your input files are rather large. If you have over 500,000 lines in your files, it means your script will consume large amounts of memory to run. It may be worthwhile for you to use a module such as [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::File) and work only with array indexes. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $filename or die $!;
for my $lineno (shuffle 0 .. $#file) {
    print $line[$lineno];
}
untie @file; # all done
```

Comment: Hi TLP, I appreciate your help, I just don't know how to implement your suggestions. How do I set a value for $header_size ? Also, the Tie::File suggestion sounds great, but I just don't know how to use the script that you suggested. Scripting isn't my background and I guess I require some extreme hand-holding.

Comment: `$header_size = 10`, for example. If you didn't know that, I see no possible way that you could write such a script. `Tie::File` is really not much different from opening a file for read/write. The difference is that instead of a file handle, you get an array where the entire file is stored. Except, of course, the file content is stored on the disk, not RAM. Similar to: `@file_content = <FILE>`. `$file_content[0]` is the first line of the file, `$file_content[-1]` is the last. Read the documentation for Tie::File, it is rather simple.

Comment: So what value does '10' as the header_size refer to? Also, where in the script would I set the value?

Comment: It determines how many indices are used when printing the arrays.

Comment: Sorry - how do I decide which value to set?

Comment: There's no way for me to know. It depends on how your input looks, and what you want out of it. I would guess that it should include all indices, which would be `$#array` when printing `@array`.